# Fourier Transform in the Path Integral of a Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, harmonic-oscillator, fourier-transform, path-integral

My question comes directly from Section 7 of Srednicki's QFT textbook. I'm not able to reproduce Equation (7.5):

$$\begin{aligned}
[\cdots]=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{d E}{2 \pi} \frac{d E^{\prime}}{2 \pi} e^{-i\left(E+E^{\prime}\right) t}[&\left(-(1+i \epsilon) E E^{\prime}-(1-i \epsilon) \omega^{2}\right) \widetilde{q}(E) \widetilde{q}\left(E^{\prime}\right) \\
&\left.+\widetilde{f}(E) \widetilde{q}\left(E^{\prime}\right)+\widetilde{f}\left(E^{\prime}\right) \widetilde{q}(E)\right].
\end{aligned}\tag{7.5}$$

I'm trying to use the Fourier-transformed variables:

$$\widetilde{q}(E)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d t e^{i E t} q(t), \quad q(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{d E}{2 \pi} e^{-i E t} \widetilde{q}(E)\tag{7.4}$$

to transform the bracketed expression that appears within (7.3):

$$\left[\frac{1}{2}(1+i \epsilon) m \dot{q}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}(1-i \epsilon) m \omega^{2} q^{2}+f q\right].\tag{7.3}$$

In fact, this question was asked previously here: [QFT: Srednicki Eq. 7.5](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/384128/)

My specific issue is not fully answered in that post. I'm wondering about how the source terms

$$+\widetilde{f}(E) \widetilde{q}\left(E^{\prime}\right)+\widetilde{f}\left(E^{\prime}\right) \widetilde{q}(E)\tag{7.5}$$

are achieved/justified? I understand (from reading the comments on the answer from the older post) that the splitting up the $\tilde{q}(E) \tilde{f}\left(E^{\prime}\right)$ term is necessary to reproduce the $\frac{1}{2}$ pre-factor. I don't see why the $E$ and $E^\prime$ integration variable must appear in the argument of either function, in the way that it does.

Comment: the $E,E'$ are integration variables, so $\int dE dE' G(E,E')=\frac{1}{2}\int dE dE' [G(E,E')+G(E',E)]$.

Comment: Even this seemingly trivial fact from calculus is not obvious to me. Why is that the case?

Comment: By relabelling the integration variables.